# Loading an array of images inside a cycle "each" using .brand and $(this) and load the lables with html function

Tags: jquery

this is the code of my course project and honestly I am stucked with it because no one has taught me how to load images inside a cycle each. So I don't know how to start

I've been reading e-books about Jquery, but I haven't found anything yet

```
enter code here <script> var productos = new Array("afrodita.png","arpia.jpg","basilisco.jpg","caballo.jpg","centauro.jpg","fenix.jpg","gea.jpg","grifo.png","hidra.gif","kraken.jpg","medusa.png","minotauro.jpg","pegaso.jpg","poseidon.jpg","quimera.jpg","satiro.jpg","unicornio.jpg");
enter code here var t="";
enter code here window.onload=function(){
//load the images in the divisions
$(".Brand").each(function(i,elemento){
```

Answer (score 0):

A little effort in search and documentation will also help you. Your problem is basic, I just hope I helped a bit with your homework :)

```
// select your html element where you need to add the images
var el = document.querySelector('.your-html-element-class');

// loop through your array and add the images into the element above
for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; ++i) {
    el.innerHTML += "<p><img src=\""+productos[i]+"\" /></p>";

}
```